# Segmentation fault in C. Trying to swap two values using pointer

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, swap

I am getting a segmentation fault while trying to attempt swapping values in two variables. My **code** is :

```
void swap(int *a,int *b){
    int *temp;
    *temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=*temp;
}
int main(){
    int i=1,j=0;
    printf("Before %d,%d\n",i,j);
    swap(&i,&j);
    printf("After %d,%d\n",i,j);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following **error**:

```
Before 1,0
After 0,1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What looks mysterious to me is the error is being produced after the values have been swapped successfully. What is the bug? Do I need to typecast the pointers anywhere?

Comment: this line: int *temp; is a pointer, that points to la-la land.  then the code performs: *temp=*a;  The result is some value has stepped on memory at 'some' unknown location. (probably in the address range of your program.  Later that corrupted memory causes the seg fault.  Much better to perform the swap with 3 xor statements.  No temp variable, only 3 instructions, and no worries about corrupting memory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your pointer `int *temp;` points on nothing.

So, when your program does `*temp=*a;`, it puts value of `a` into random memory block.

Try this fix:

```
void swap(int *a,int *b){
    int temp;
    temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}
```

**Updated**:

Additional question:

> Suppose I want to use temp as a pointer variable and not as a regular
>   variable, is there any way to get my program executed or I need to
>   leave my stubbornness?

Answer: you can try this:

```
void swap(int *a,int *b){
    int *temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (temp == NULL)
      return;
    *temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=*temp;
    free(temp);
}
```

Comment: Suppose I want to use `temp` as a pointer variable and not as a regular variable, is there any way to get my program executed or I need to leave my stubbornness?

Comment: @Ilya I think that whenever compilers see an attempt to malloc() a small constant size, it should print an insult and quit.

Comment: @Ajay I hope you are "just" trolling.

Comment: @Will why do you think so?

Comment: @Ajay, no! It is good practice to set variable to NULL **after** `free()`. But it is ridiculous do it before call of `free()`.

Comment: @llya i think that if two pointer points to the same memory space and you are freeing one of the pointer then the other pointer will points to nothing(act as a dangling pointer). For safe side just make the freeing pointer equal to NULL and than use free(temp);

Comment: @Will : so as to learn by using a temp pointer. I realize that I should have `malloc/calloc`ed the pointer to get some space for variable and getting the pointer alone does not permit me to put any value in it. Thanks all !!

Comment: @Will, I agree with you. But sometimes we have allocation and deallocation in different functions/modules. In this case it is good practice to set variable to NULL after deallocation.

Comment: @Gaurav Okay, but keep in mind that normally there are only two good reasons to ever use m/c/realloc(): 1) when you don't know the size of your variable/array at compile time, or 2) when you need an amount of memory large enough that it could blow up the stack, and you don't want a global or static memory duration.

Answer (score 3):

Your `swap` function is wrong. It should be

```
void swap(int *a,int *b){
  int temp = *a;
  *a= *b;
  *b= temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this swap function :-

```
void swap(int *a,int *b){
    int temp;
    temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
   }
```